# Playframework 1.2.5 custom module never hit

Tags: module, playframework

Steps:

1. **play new-module firstmodule**
2. Updated the **play.plugins** file of the module to include

   ```
   10:play.modules.firstmodule.MyPlugin
   ```
3. Create the **MyPlugin** class:

   ```
   package play.modules.firstmodule;

   import play.Logger;
   import play.PlayPlugin;

   public class MyPlugin extends PlayPlugin {
       @Override
       public void onLoad() {
           Logger.info("hello");
       }

       @Override
       public void onApplicationStart() {
           Logger.info("hello");
       }

       @Override
       public void onRoutesLoaded() {
           Logger.info("hello");
       }
   }
   ```
4. **play build-module**
5. Add module to main project dependencies

   ```
   require:
       - play 1.2.5
       - customModules -> firstmodule

   repositories:
       - playCustomModules:
           type:       local
           artifact:   c:\github\firstmodule\dist\firstmodule-0.1.zip
           contains:
               - customModules -> *
   ```
6. **play deps** resolves all dependencies correctly
7. **play run**

Server starts and I hit any page, but the log message "hello" is never printed. What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Got it worked?

I had to also add the same `play.plugins` files to the main `proyect /conf` directory to make it work.